# formula – conditional return on a column containing "Yes"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to write a formula in an Excel worksheet
that will return a value when a specific cell contains the word, "Yes".

The formula I want Excel to run if the condition is met is essentially checking the date above the cell for the result against how long that cost should run for; e.g., April 2021 to December 2022. 
The current formula that returns the value based on date is:

```
=IF(AND(AJ$5>=$H24,AJ$5<=$I24),$J24,0)
```

where:

- AJ5 is the current month,
- H24 is the start date of the cost,
- I24 is the end date of the cost,
- J24 is the monthly cost

So if a cell contains "Yes",
Excel would then run the date check formula and return the value. 
If the qualifying cell contains "No", it would return 0.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say “checking the date above the cell”,
and “the current month” is in `AJ5`,
I assume that the “Yes” (or something else) is in `AJ6`. 
The general way to do what you seem to be asking for
is simply to use a compound `IF`; i.e., an `IF` within an `IF`, like this:

```
=IF(AJ6="Yes",  IF(AND(AJ$5>=$H24,AJ$5<=$I24),$J24,0),  0)
```

But, in this case, since the formula you already have is an `IF`
with the same “else” value (`0`)
— and it contains an `AND` — you can simplify it a little:

```
=IF(AND(AJ6="Yes",AJ$5>=$H24,AJ$5<=$I24),$J24,0)
```

You haven’t explained why you use `$`s some places but not others. 
I’ll assume that you know what you’re doing,
and leave it to you to figure out
whether you need to use `AJ6`, `AJ$6`, `$AJ6` or  `$AJ$6`