# I want to substract only if m cell contain Yes

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft

I want to substract B7- N7 only if M7 contain Yes.... Can you please tell me how to do this. I tried isblank formula but it is not happening... Please tell me how to do it

Comment: =IF(M7="Yes",B7-N7,"")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [formula – conditional return on a column containing "Yes"](https://superuser.com/questions/1686306/formula-conditional-return-on-a-column-containing-yes)

Comment: If there are other characters besides “Yes”, you can try adding wildcards.